# MediaStore API is unable to fetch the folder which is already created before Clear Data of the Application

Tags: android, mediastore, android-storage

To support Android 11 storage, I have implemented **Scoped Storage** - MediaStore API successfully. However, I ended up with one scenario which I am not sure how to resolve. Scenario is, When the Application is launched for the first time, we have created the Folder under **Documents** folder and able to read and write files into this folder without creating any duplicate folders. However, If I do **Clear Data** and re-login the Application, I am not able to fetch the folder which is already created and each time it is creating a new folder with duplicate name - Suffix as (2), (3) etc..,

Please find my code which I tired and also find the screenshots.

```
         File folder = null;
         String folderName = "Duration";
         if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            String filePath = FileUtils.readFileExternalStorage(contentUri,context,folderName).getPath();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath) && FileUtils.isFileExisting(filePath)) {
                folder = new File(filePath);
            } else {
                Uri uri = FileUtils.createFileExternalStorage(contentUri,context,folderName),Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
                Commons.print("URI "+uri.getPath());
                folder = new File(FileUtils.getPath(context,uri));
            }
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
      
        } else {
         
            folder = getStorageDir(folderName);
            bmodel.deleteFiles(getStorageDir(folderName) + "/", filename);
        }

        File file = new File(folder, filename );
        if(file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        if (SynchronizationHelper.bcpJSONData != null) {
            FileOutputStream outputStream;
            try {
                Commons.print("FilePath " + file.getPath());

                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);//context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(SynchronizationHelper.bcpJSONData.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
                outputStream = null;
                SynchronizationHelper.bcpJSONData = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This is FileUtils class:

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public static File readFileExternalStorage(Uri contentUri, Context context, String filename) {

    final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?";
    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {filename};
    return new File(getDataColumn(context,contentUri,selection,selectionArgs));
}

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public static Uri createFileExternalStorage(Uri contentUri, Context context, String filename, String folder) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, folder);
    return context.getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, values);
}

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri,
                                   String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = { column };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return "";
}

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // check here to KITKAT or new version
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return "";
}
```

On every instance after clearing data of the application, this method `getDataColumn()` is returning "" empty and on Debugging I found that the Cursor inside the `try` block, is not fetching anything out of it.

[image: Please find the Document Folder below from File Manager]

Answer (score 0):

Well, You should consider 2 things first.

**1. Don't create the folder if it already exists**

**2. Load media from the folder with different code**

So, here is a little help.

**1. Check the existence of the directory.**

```
if (!file.exists()) {
                    createFolder();
                }
```

Then

**2. Load media differently**

```
private ArrayList<Media> loadMedia(String directory_name) {
        mediaList = new ArrayList<>();
        String selection;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH + " LIKE ? ";
        } else {
            selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? ";
        }

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{directory_name};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
                null,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    int imageCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));
                    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                    long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED));
                    String pathId = cursor.getString(imageCol);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(pathId);
                    Uri contentUri;
                    if (uri.toString().endsWith(".mp4")) {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                    } else {
                        contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
                    }
                    Media media = new Media();
                    media.setPath(path);
                    media.setMediaStoreUri(contentUri);
                    media.setUri(uri);
                    media.setAlbumName(new File(path).getParent());
                    mediaList.add(media);
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return mediaList;
    }
```

This code is working perfectly in all of the devices including Android 10 and above. Give it a try.

All the best!

Comment: it is not solving the problem

Comment: What's your device's android version?

Comment: android 10 and I haven't set `requestlegacyexternalstorage` to true

Comment: It's not needed with mediastore API. Can you print the log of total row counts from cursor? How many does it show?

Comment: whenever I uninstall app or clear the data, the files aren't accessible anymore. For example, after clearing data  I can only access files which I make after that . The ones I made before clearing data are still there but not accessible anymore.

Comment: Not possible. I've used this code in many apps & able to access all the files. Let me edit my answer with the latest changes.

Comment: when I use your code it fetch nothing. the cursor count is 0. I tried your code but not using it right now, this behavior is in my code

Comment: Where is the Media class imported from?